# Find relevant records with multiple options

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wasn't sure how I should name the Question. I try to explanin what I need to achieve.

I will get a list from our Customer where the installed software on each machin will be listed.

**Example_**
Machines List

```
Hostname  SW
PC001     SW001
PC001     SW002
PC002     SW003
PC002     SW001
PC003     SW003
```

**Software List**

```
SW Name   Status
SW001     not okay
SW002     not okay
SW003     ready
```

I need to have an SQL or MS-Access logik to find all Hostname which have only SW installed with Status okay

and - in adition - i need a logic to tell me what kind of SW product need to be okay to make additional Hostnames availabale with only okay Software installed.

At the moment i struggle with this question

rgds
Sebastian

Comment: If i understand you right, all you have to do is to so make sql queries which are gonna provide you the relevant data.

Comment: Write some queries and show them to us. You need to make the effort.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i am not sure how to select the multiple rows one Hostname could have as the whole - so If i use a select statement i get all Hostname where the specified product is installed - but other installed products aren't reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Well i could help you a bit, but you have to do something by yourself,

So first of all i modified your DDL code first

```
CREATE TABLE `machines` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hostnames` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `id_soft` int(11) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE `software` (
 `id_soft` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `software_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
```

--

### -- Indexes for table `machines`

```
 ALTER TABLE `machines`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ADD KEY `id_soft` (`id_soft`);
```

--

### -- Indexes for table `software`

```
 ALTER TABLE `software`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_soft`);
```

--

### -- Constraints for table `machines`

```
 ALTER TABLE `machines`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `machines_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_soft`) REFERENCES 
`software` (`id_soft`);
```

and here is your query for showing hostnames only where the status is okey or ready!

```
SELECT hostnames
FROM machines
LEFT JOIN software on machines.id_soft = software.id_soft
WHERE machines.id_soft = (SELECT software.id_soft from software 
            WHERE software.status like 'ready');
```

So this will definitely help you but you have to do other things alone, and only if you cant find a solution, we will be here to get help you.